# How to create a query to get invoices between dates (help needed)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a query in SQL to get some invoices depending on the current date. I'm an intern in the company, so I only need to create the logic, not necessarily the query. Can anyone help me to translate this conditions into SQL (Snowflake)?

- If Current Date (today's date) is between day 14 and 27 of the month >>> Get
  invoices from day 14 of the current month
- If Current Date (today's date) is between day 28 and 31 of the month >>> Get
  invoices from day 28 of the current month
- If Current Date (today's date) is between day 1 and 13 of the month >>> Get invoices
  from day 28 of the last month

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think your simplest, clearest option is a case statement.
You can put this into your select and work with it from there, or put it directly into a where clause. whatever's more appropriate for your query.

```sql
WHERE invoice_date::DATE = (CASE WHEN DAY(current_date) between 14 and 27 then DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(current_date), MONTH(current_date), 14)
                                 WHEN DAY(current_date) between 28 and 31 then DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(current_date), MONTH(current_date), 28)
                                 WHEN DAY(current_date) between 1 and 13  then DATEADD('month', -1, DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(current_date), MONTH(current_date), 28))
                                 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
   current_date()+1 your_date
   ,dateadd(day,27-(sign(FLOOR(day(your_date)/14,0))*14) 
     ,dateadd(month,sign(FLOOR(day(your_date)/14,0))-1 
     ,date_trunc(month,your_date))) your_result
```

Revised solution.

Removing inequalities and reducing the problem down to multiples of 14 with month adjustments instead of multiple case statements (expensive to run at scale).

[image]

Comment: this might work, but the code is pretty cryptic to me. It's very hard for me to look at this and understand/predict what value is going to be returned for a given date. I also can't see why it would run faster since it needs to generate and compare all of the dates rather than just one.

Comment: Also, I think you need your filter prior to running the `GREATEST`. I can't get this to work correctly for some dates.

Comment: Runs faster as there's no case statements or inequality predicates.  You were correct my previous answer wasn't tested perfectly - apologies.